# Cant log into Ubuntu 20.04 Samba share from Windows 10

Tags: samba

I'm at my wit's end. I've tried everything but can't get a samba share on Ubuntu 20.04 to work from Windows 10.

On Ubuntu, i installed samba and made a folder /home/share.  I created a linux user "samba" and added it to the samba group with smbpasswd -a samba.  I then chown'd the folder to samba:sambashare.

The relevant section of my smb.conf:

```
[sharefolder]
        comment = public
        path = /home/share
        create mask = 0664
        guest ok = yes
        public = yes
        browseable = yes
        writable = yes
        readonly = no
```

I've turned off firewalls on both machines temporarily to make sure there is no interference.  I enabled smb1 on the add windows features page.  I enabled insecure guest logins in gpedit.

Under This PC, opening Run and using either the lan ip or the hostname of the ubuntu box (\server\sharefolder) or (\192.168.x.xxx\sharefolder) I get Windows cannot access \server\sharefolder.  You do not have permission to access \server\sharefolder.
Trying Add a network location in This PC for \server\sharefolder I get a credentials login popup.  Trying samba for user and entering the password I get "The folder you entered does not appear to be valid.  Please choose another."
Trying Map a Network Drive to \server\sharefolder as Drive X: and selecting "connect using different credentials" using username samba just finally worked after I typed all this, when it previously did not.

Can anyone tell me why it took mapping the drive to get it to work?